# Kivy Producer/Consumer Queue Updates

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kivy

Looking to understand why this code is not updating.  Any help is much appreciated.
TJ

Here is my Main.py. Here, I'm attempting to link up a queue that stores the state of a number producer process.  This is to simulate some background process that will update the user interface over time.

```
import Consumer
import Producer
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
   shared_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

  producer = Producer.NumberGenerator(shared_queue)
   multiprocessing.Process(target=producer.generate_numbers).start()

  app = Consumer.TimerApp()
   app.set_queue(shared_queue)

  app.run()
```

Producer.py runs as a separate process that generates a new number once a second.  It's just there to show that a background task is able to continually update the user interface.

```
import time


class NumberGenerator(object):

   def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q
        self.counter = 0

   def generate_numbers(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.counter += 1
            # print self.counter
            self.q.put(self.counter)
```

Consumer.py is our Kivy app.  It is meant to listen to the queue by popping items from it. Then, update the UI to demonstrate things are working.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import multiprocessing


class YourWidget(Label):
   temp = StringProperty()

  def update_text(self, txt):
      self.temp = txt


class TimerApp(App):

  def build(self):
      self.widget = YourWidget()
      self.widget.update_text("Initial Text!")

     # Build registry here
      # Start queue reader here
      # How do I pass in a reference? Setter function??
      return self.widget

  def set_queue(self, q):
      self.q = q

  def consumer_process_queue(self):
      while True:
         value = str(self.q.get())
         print "Consumer: {}".format(value)
         self.widget.update_text(value)

  def on_start(self):
      # self.widget.update_text("Hello World!")
      multiprocessing.Process(target=self.consumer_process_queue).start()
```

timer.kv:

```
<YourWidget>:
    text: root.temp
```

When things are processing, I can see the numbers updating to STDOUT.  This indicates that "self.widget.update_text(value)" is not doing what I want it to.
Any ideas?

Also, if I use the commented "self.widget.update_text("Hello World!")" code and comment out the "multiprocessing.Process(target=self.consumer_process_queue).start()", the widget updates the text.

Comment: Could this issue be caused by something like being in the wrong context when attempting to publish an update?

Comment: Tried modifying the consumer queue code to see if I could force updates.  See the code below.  Didn't help. 

`def consumer_process_queue(self):
      while True:
         time.sleep(0.5)
         value = str(self.q.get())
         print "Consumer: {}".format(value)
         # self.widget.update_text(value)
         self.widget.text = str(value)
         self.widget.canvas.ask_update()
`

Comment: (1) Remove the "while True" and adjust the indentation in the consumer_process_queue() method. (2) Add "from kivy.clock import Clock". (3) Add "Clock.schedule_interval(self.consumer_process_queue, 1)"  in the build() method. Please refer to my example for details.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

```
def consumer_process_queue(self):
    while True:
        value = str(self.q.get())
        print("Consumer: {}".format(value))
        self.widget.update_text(value)
```

When you run this, the program will never exit your loop, preventing Kivy from doing all of the other things that need doing. As a result, all you’ll see is a black window with "Initial Text!", which you won’t be able to interact with.

## Solution

Instead, you need to “schedule” your consumer_process_queue() function to be called repeatedly.
Please refer to the example for details. No changes to Producer.py and main.py.

## Example

### Consumer.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
import multiprocessing


class YourWidget(Label):

    def update_text(self, txt):
        self.text = txt


class TimerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.widget = YourWidget()
        self.widget.update_text("Initial Text!")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.consumer_process_queue, 1)

        # Build registry here
        # Start queue reader here
        # How do I pass in a reference? Setter function??
        return self.widget

    def set_queue(self, q):
        self.q = q

    def consumer_process_queue(self, dt=0):
        value = str(self.q.get())
        print("Consumer: {}".format(value))
        self.widget.update_text(value)

    def on_start(self):
        # self.update_text("Hello World!")
        multiprocessing.Process(target=self.consumer_process_queue).start()
```

### timer.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<YourWidget>:
    text: ""
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you!